# How to get a Map owned by an Object as an attribute from a List of these objects

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, java-10

I have an `BOLReference` object as follows:

```
private String ediTransmissionId;
private List<WorkflowExceptions> workflowExceptions;
```

And the inner `WorkflowExceptions` looks like below:

```
private String category;
private Map<String,String> businessKeyValues;
```

I want to get a particular `Map<String,String>` ***businessKeyValues*** from the *list* of `WorkflowExceptions` based on some filters. How can I do so?

```
        Map<String,String> bKeyMap = bolRef.get(0).getWorkflowExceptions()
            .stream().filter(wk->wk.getBusinessKeyValues().containsKey("ABC123"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain the ***map*** `businessKeyValues` that contains a certain *key*, first, you need to apply `map()` operation to extract the *map* from a `WorkflowExceptions` object.

Then apply `filter()` operation as you've done in your code. And `findFirst()` (*which returns the first encountered element in the stream*) as a terminal operation.

Method `findFirst()` returns an *optional* object, because the result may or may not be present in the stream. [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class offers you a wide variety of methods that allow to treat the situation when result is not present in different ways depending on your needs. Down below I've used `orElse()` method that'll provide an *empty map* if result wasn't found.

Other options you might consider: `orElseThrow()`, `orElseGet()`, `or()` (*in conjunction with other methods*).

```
Map<String,String> bKeyMap = bolRef.get(0).getWorkflowExceptions()
                .stream()
                .map(WorkflowExceptions::getBusinessKeyValues)
                .filter(bkv -> bkv.containsKey("ABC123"))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```